# Linq query with inner join, multiple group by and min max

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-entities, group-by, min

I'm trying to convert the following query to linq.

```
SELECT        Client.Nom, Client.Prenom AS Prénom, Client.Structure, MIN(Meeting.Start) AS Début, MAX(Meeting.Start) AS Fin, Meeting.Dispositifs AS Dispositif
FROM            Meeting INNER JOIN
                         Client ON Meeting.CliID = Client.CliID
WHERE        (Client.Nom LIKE 'kess%')
GROUP BY Client.Nom, Client.Prenom, Client.Structure, Meeting.Dispositifs
ORDER BY Début DESC, Fin
```

What I have so far is this:

```
var clients = this.ObjectContext.Clients;
            var meetings = this.ObjectContext.Meetings;

            //int i = 0;

            var query = from personne in clients
                        join meeting in meetings on personne.CliID equals meeting.CliID
                        where personne.CliID == guid
                        group personne by new { personne.Nom, personne.Prenom, personne.Structure, meeting.Dispositifs } into g
                        select new Parcour
                        {
                            //ID = i++,
                            Nom = g.Key.Nom,
                            Prénom = g.Key.Prenom,
                            Structure = g.Key.Structure,
                            Début = g.Min(m => m.Start),
                            Fin = g.Max(m => m.Start),
                            Dispositif = g.Key.Dispositifs,
                        };

            return query.ToList<Parcour>();
```

My problem is to get access to the Start property which is a property of meeting.

Also, is there a way to have a key like ID here that would contain an int that gets autoincremented?

Any help would be much appreciated,
John.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's fix the LINQ. It's [nearly always wrong](https://web.archive.org/web/20160315043506/http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/) to use `join` in LINQ to Entities.

Also, you seem to be using the SQL `GROUP BY` solely to facilitate use of the aggregate `MIN` and `MAX` per-client. LINQ to Entities doesn't require this. So we can simplify that, too.

That leaves us with.

```
        var query = from personne in clients
                    where personne.CliID == guid
                        && personne.Meetings.Any() // simulate `INNER JOIN` 
                                                   // retirer les gens sans réunions
                                                   // pardonne mon français terrible, STP
                    select new Parcour
                    {
                        //ID = i++,
                        Nom = personne.Nom,
                        Prénom = personne.Prenom,
                        Structure = personne.Structure,
                        Début = personne.Meetings.Min(m => m.Start),
                        Fin = personne.Meetings.Max(m => m.Start),
                        Dispositif = personne.Dispositifs,
                    };
```

Then you ask:

> Also, is there a way to have a key like ID here that would contain an int that gets autoincremented?

It's not clear what you want here.

If you want a *database key*, then use an AUTOINCREMENT column. EF supports that.

If you want an incrementing number for *this method only*, then us the [indexed overload to Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx).